# Initializing (allocated) memory without calling destructor, copy, or move

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a memory I allocated with `VirtualAlloc` and I have cast the type to some struct I created:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    uint32 SomeInt;
    Class SomeClass;
};
```

like this:

```
MemoryBlock = VirtualAlloc(0, SizeInBytes, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
SomeStruct* NewPointer = (SomeStruct*)MemoryBlock ;
```

All the memory is initalized to zero BUT I have a problem with that, in the `Class` class I created, there is member of type `std::unordered_map<std::string, int32>`.

The problem is, when I try to use `NewPointer->SomeClass` it wont work and throw `read access violation` exception, which is right, but when I try to do this:

```
*NewPointer = {};
```

To initialize the struct (Including `NewPointer->SomeClass`) I get another exception about moving the `std::unordered_map<std::string, int32>` (again, `read access violation` exception).

The error is thrown here:
[image]

(On the line where I initialize)

which I traced back to here:
[image]

I don't really get what happens but I think it has something to do with moving the data or destructing it.

What can I do to make the above code work and for me to use `SomeClass` without causing exceptions?

By the way, I have to use the the allocated memory so I can't remove it.
(I am sending the allocated memory to another .dll so I don't know the struct type when allocating the memory)

Comment: Don't post code as images. Copy and past the code into the question itself.

Comment: Its the code of 'xhash' and 'list' files not my code..

Comment: @Zik332 Use placement `new` to overcome these problems. Constructors and destructors must be called properly and there's no way to overcome this.

Comment: @user0042 Forgot to mention, that is what I am trying to avoid, using new. that is why I allocated a big chunk of memory. Are you sure there isn't a way to overcome this?

Comment: @Zik332 Placement `new` will operate on the memory you allocated in your  custom way. That's the whole point of it. Check [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew about that, I'll check that out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it would be to use placement new:

```
auto* MemoryBlock = VirtualAlloc(0, SizeInBytes, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
SomeStruct* NewPointer = new (MemoryBlock) SomeStruct();

// ...

NewPointer->~SomeStruct();
VirtualFree(MemoryBlock /*..*/)
```